# Is there a keyboard shortcut of navigate-back-to-previous-location for the Google Apps Script Programming Environment?

Tags: google-apps-script, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, monaco-editor

If I push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> to go to the definition of function. I would like to go back to previous location. In VS code, I can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left-Arrow</kbd> to go back.
In Google Apps Script Programming Environment(in Chrome web browser, windows 10), I also tried to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left-arrow</kbd>, but it triggered to go back to previous page, which is the function of web browser.
I expected it can go back to previous editing location, but it was not.
Is there a keyboard shortcut of navigate-back-to-previous-location for the Google Apps Script Programming Environment? Thanks.

Comment: At the moment, there is no defined keyboard shortcut on Google Apps Script to jump back to the previous location of editing, although there are alternative shortcuts available to find and scroll through the locations of the defined function, like `Ctrl + F3` or `Ctrl + Shift + F3`.

Comment: As such, you can [submit a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) instead for this specific functionality.